# My loop wont start for my fibonacci java code

Tags: java

I need to create a Fibonacci project for my class and my loop doesn't want to start

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FibonacciGenerator{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the amount of fibonaccis you want: ");
        int ny = sd.nextInt();
        Fibonacci num = new Fibonacci(ny);

        System.out.println(num.getFib1());
        System.out.println(num.getFib2());

        for(int i = 1; i < ny; i++){
            System.out.println(num.nextNumber());
            num  = new Fibonacci(ny);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my derived class for those asking for what each class did

```
public class Fibonacci {
    private int n;
    private int fib1;
    private int fib2;
    private int fib3;

    public Fibonacci(int ny){
        n=ny;
        fib1=1;
        fib2=1;
        fib3=0;
    }
    public int nextNumber() {
        while(n>2) {
            fib3=fib1+fib2;
            fib1=fib2;
            fib2=fib3;
        }
        return fib3;
    }
    public int getFib1() {
        return fib1;
    }
    public int getFib2() {
        return fib2;
    }
}
```

hopefully, the issue isn't just right in front of my eyes and I don't see it. Trying to get into coding so this is a start.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: Your loop doesn't "want" anything.  It doesn't have a will of its own.  What your program *does* do is execute exactly what logic it's written to do.  Sounds like now is the time for you to familiarize yourself with debugging.  This is often a good place to start: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs

Comment: You have not provided Fibonacci class

Comment: consider adding some information about classes you have used in your code

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: and you are re-assigning variable num in each iteration

Comment: Debugging with println() is quite good, why not.

You might consider specifying how it should behave before doing actual desing/coding, like this:

$java com.Fibinacci

Enter the amount of fibonaccis you want: 10

Fibonacci numbers are:
1 1 2 3 5 ...
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i had to do it I'd choose a different aproach - but it's your program, so I only fixed your errors:

```
public class  Fibonacci {
    private int n;
    private int fib1;
    private int fib2;
    private int fib3;

    public Fibonacci(int ny){
        n=ny;
        fib1=1;
        fib2=1;
        fib3=0;
    }
    public int nextNumber() {
        while(n-->2) {
            fib3=fib1+fib2;
            fib1=fib2;
            fib2=fib3;
        }
        return fib3;
    }
    public int getFib1() {
        return fib1;
    }
    public int getFib2() {
        return fib2;
    }
}
public class FibonacciGenerator{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the amount of fibonaccis you want: ");
        int ny = sd.nextInt();
        Fibonacci num = new Fibonacci(ny);

        System.out.println(num.getFib1());
        System.out.println(num.getFib2());

        for(int i = 3; i < ny; i++){
            num  = new Fibonacci(i);
            System.out.println(num.nextNumber());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your Fibonacci class look like this?

```
class FibonacciExample1{  
    public static void main(String args[]){    
        int n1=0,n2=1,n3,i,count=10;    
        System.out.print(n1+" "+n2);

        for(i=2;i<count;++i) {    
            n3=n1+n2;    
            System.out.print(" "+n3);    
            n1=n2;    
            n2=n3;    
        }
    }
}
```

example taken from [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/fibonacci-series-in-java)